# MySQL sql_mode error. Showing '0 rows affected.'

Tags: mysql

So, On our Counter-Strike server, we're using plugin, that's coded in NULLS. Strict mode is blocking the NULLS. We need to turn off the strict mode. We tried it many times. We wrote this:

```
set sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

We don't have permissions to use:

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

When I'll set the command, this will come up:

```
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.000 s)
```

Then I'll use command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

This will pop-up:

```
sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If you can't set the variable globally, it will only affect the current connection. If your connection is renewed on every query (for example if you use phpMyAdmin), then it's fruitless to set variables in session scope, because the change disappears at the end of the request.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by strict mode blocking NULLs. There's nothing wrong with NULLs in strict mode. I suggest you figure out what's really going on, because strict mode is generally a good thing. It helps prevent you from creating bogus data or queries.

Comment: I'm using adminer, I'm really new to this. I just want to know, If there's any way to do it. The MySQL was free to the server. So I think they'll not give you the global permissions, and if I can ask, If I'll get the global permissions, When I 'll do the set global, it'll be only on the one database, or on all databases connected to localhost? (There're more than 5000 databates created on.)

Comment: KZTimer uses NULL dates and strict mode doesn't let it insert them into the table. This can be solved by disabling strict mode though. 

Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

Comment: '0000-00-00' is not NULL and it's not a date. It's a string full of zeroes and dashes. There is no such date, because zeroes are not used for month or day numbers in the Gregorian calendar. It's correct to disallow this date. If you want a value that means "no date" then use NULL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Setting global variables in MySQL affects _all_ databases on the instance, not just one database. If you're on a shared server, that's probably why they don't give you the privileges to set global variables. It requires SUPER privilege to change global variables, and with that privilege you could do a lot of damage by accident to their server and all the other users.

Comment: FWIW, I recall Adminer is also a PHP application, so it has the same trait as phpMyAdmin: every request opens a new database connection. So changing a session variable will not affect subsequent requests.

Comment: He just wrote, to remove the strict mode, still thanks.